# How to know how to sketch $\cos^2 x$ graphs from $\cos x$?

Tags: graphing-functions, spherical-harmonics

> How to know how to sketch $\cos^2 x$ graphs from $\cos x$?

I am trying to understand spherical harmonics, but I need to brush up on my fundamentals to understand it faster and better.

For example, $\cos x$ graphs peaks at 0 and $\pi$, but what about $\cos^2 x $ graphs?

How do I understand where it peaks for $\cos^2 x$ ? I've been told to visualise it as $2 cosine graphs, but what does that mean?

Comment: For every $x$-value, take the $y$-value of the $\cos$ graph and square it. $\cos^2$ then has a maximum wherever $\cos$ is furthest away from the $x$-axis, and a minimum wherever $\cos$ is closest to the $x$-axis.

Comment: $\cos^{2}x=\frac {1+\cos(2x)} 2$.